# Skills Assessment for Australian Visa

Tags: australia

I want to get an Independent Visa (189) for Australia. For this I need to do a Skills Assessment with a specific Assessment Authority. I am a Physicist and I don't know what my proper Assessment Authority is. Checking the [official webpage](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/working-in-australia/skills-assessment/assessing-authorities), I don't get any results at all for any official Assessment Authorities. Using Google I found some (official?) Assessment Authorities, but not for Physics.

How do I need to proceed to get my Skills Assessment?

Comment: Perhaps instead of searching for "physicist" you could choose the actual occupation you now hold or are seeking. For example, "academic" or "professor" or "researcher" or "scientist" might generate a response.

Comment: I couldn't get anything to come up on one search even for jobs that I knew were listed. Instead I followed a link to the [legislation](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2019L00278): 234914 (ANZSCO code), VETASSESS/ACPSEM (assessing authority).